# CakePHP 3 - finder not loading correct data

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I have a table called `Bookings`, with the following attributes:

- `id`
- `artist_id` - foreign key
- `status`
- `amount`
- `created`
- `modified`

It is associated with tables `Artists`, `Payments` and `Sessions`.

In the View, I have used the jQuery plugin DataTables to display `Bookings` which meet the following conditions:

- Their `status` is equal to 'confirmed'
- Associated table `Session's` attribute `date_end` must be greater than the current date.

However, the second condition does not seem to work in that it returns nothing when data entries which do meet that condition exist.

In my controller, the corresponding find for this particular table:

```
$bookingsConfirmed = $this->Bookings->find('all',[
            'contain' => ['Sessions', 'Sessions.Studios', 'Sessions.Engineers', 'Artists'],
            'conditions'=>['status' => 'confirmed', 'Sessions.date_end >=' => DATE(Time::now())],
            'order'=>['Bookings.created'=>'ASC']
        ]);
```

I've attempted the following changes to the condition, all of which showed no notable difference:

- `date_end >=' => DATE(Time::now())`
- `'Sessions.date_end >=' => Time::now()`
- `'date(Sessions.date_end) >=' => DATE(Time::now())`
- `'date(Sessions.date_end) >=' => date(DATE(Time::now()))`

If I switch around the >= sign to a <, all my booking data appear, despite not all of them meeting that condition.

In the SQL log, this is the output for this particular table:

```
SELECT 
  Bookings.id AS `Bookings__id`, 
  Bookings.artist_id AS `Bookings__artist_id`, 
  Bookings.status AS `Bookings__status`, 
  Bookings.amount AS `Bookings__amount`, 
  Bookings.created AS `Bookings__created`, 
  Bookings.modified AS `Bookings__modified`, 
  Sessions.id AS `Sessions__id`, 
  Sessions.booking_id AS `Sessions__booking_id`, 
  Sessions.studio_id AS `Sessions__studio_id`, 
  Sessions.engineer_id AS `Sessions__engineer_id`, 
  Sessions.guestengineer_id AS `Sessions__guestengineer_id`, 
  Sessions.date_start AS `Sessions__date_start`, 
  Sessions.date_end AS `Sessions__date_end`, 
  Sessions.starttime AS `Sessions__starttime`, 
  Sessions.hours AS `Sessions__hours`, 
  Sessions.session_genre AS `Sessions__session_genre`, 
  Sessions.no_people AS `Sessions__no_people`, 
  Sessions.studio_usage AS `Sessions__studio_usage`, 
  Sessions.otherpeople_req AS `Sessions__otherpeople_req`, 
  Sessions.special_req AS `Sessions__special_req`, 
  Sessions.created AS `Sessions__created`, 
  Sessions.modified AS `Sessions__modified`, 
  Studios.id AS `Studios__id`, 
  Studios.name AS `Studios__name`, 
  Studios.description AS `Studios__description`, 
  Studios.created AS `Studios__created`, 
  Studios.modified AS `Studios__modified`, 
  Engineers.id AS `Engineers__id`, 
  Engineers.user_id AS `Engineers__user_id`, 
  Engineers.eng_firstname AS `Engineers__eng_firstname`, 
  Engineers.eng_lastname AS `Engineers__eng_lastname`, 
  Engineers.eng_email AS `Engineers__eng_email`, 
  Engineers.eng_phoneno AS `Engineers__eng_phoneno`, 
  Engineers.eng_status AS `Engineers__eng_status`, 
  Engineers.rate AS `Engineers__rate`, 
  Engineers.created AS `Engineers__created`, 
  Engineers.modified AS `Engineers__modified`, 
  Artists.id AS `Artists__id`, 
  Artists.name AS `Artists__name`, 
  Artists.cp_id AS `Artists__cp_id`, 
  Artists.user_id AS `Artists__user_id`, 
  Artists.genre AS `Artists__genre`, 
  Artists.created AS `Artists__created`, 
  Artists.modified AS `Artists__modified` 
FROM 
  bookings Bookings 
  LEFT JOIN sessions Sessions ON Bookings.id = (Sessions.booking_id) 
  INNER JOIN studios Studios ON Studios.id = (Sessions.studio_id) 
  LEFT JOIN engineers Engineers ON Engineers.id = (Sessions.engineer_id) 
  INNER JOIN artists Artists ON Artists.id = (Bookings.artist_id) 
WHERE 
  (
    status = 'confirmed' 
    AND Sessions.date_end >= '20/2/17, 4:47 p02'
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  Bookings.created ASC
```

As of today's date, there should be 3 entries that show. I did a print of `Time::now` and got the date:

```
Cake\I18n\Time Object
(
    [time] => 2017-02-20T16:47:11+11:00
    [timezone] => 
    [fixedNowTime] => 
)
```

The odd thing is that this was working fine last week, and the submission forms still work. In MySQL for example, my latest entry that I inputted today shows Sessions.date_end filled in, in a YYYY-MM-DD format like all the entries that proceeded it.

Comment: The second variant should work just fine, given that your `date_end` column is set to a proper DATE/TIME type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this line instead

```
`date_end >=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', Time::now()->getTimestamp())`
```

Note : use the exact word case for functions, `date` instead of `DATE`

Comment: That did the trick. I attempted something similar to it before (using 'Y-m-d'), but on 'date_end' which ended up giving me syntax errors since it also uses inverted commas.